# Django - Bad request syntax or unsupported method

Tags: django

I want to post data via an api onto my django app. This is how far I got:

```
import pandas
import requests 

excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('workorders.xlsx')
json_str = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')

API_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/"
API_KEY = "dF8NbXRA.94Mj2xeXT3NZOtx1b575CvNvbs8JWo0D"
data = {'api_dev_key':API_KEY, 
        'api_option':'paste', 
        'api_paste_code':json_str , 
        'api_paste_format':'csv'} 

r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)
```

---

Django

---

views.py

```
class PostDataView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Workorder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkorderSerializer
```

---

serializers.py

```
class WorkorderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Workorder
        exclude = ['id']
```

---

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import *
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^api/chart/data/$', ChartData.as_view(),name="api-data"),
    url(r'^api/create/$', PostDataView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/api/delete/$', DeleteDataView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/api/update/$', UpdateDataView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^$', display_mobiles, name="display_mobiles"), 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', edit_mobile, name="edit_mobile"),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', delete_mobile, name="delete_mobile"),
    url(r'^home/$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^sitemap/$', sitemap, name='sitemap'),
    url(r'^upload/$', upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^test/$', testview, name='test')
]

if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

---

models.py

```
class Workorder(models.Model):
    label                       = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    start                       = models.DateField() 
    end                         = models.DateField() 
    duration                    = models.IntegerField() 
    ctype                       = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='bar')                                                                 
    werk                        = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='plant')
    product                     = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    train_number                = models.IntegerField()
    latest_start_date           = models.DateField()
    latest_start_timebucket     = models.IntegerField()
    is_start_date_fixed         = models.BooleanField()
    assigned_start_timebucket   = models.IntegerField()
    assigned_start_date         = models.DateField()
    costs_early_start           = models.IntegerField()
    costs_late_start            = models.IntegerField()
    resource_overall_demands    = models.IntegerField()
    resource_timeslots_demands  = models.IntegerField()
```

---

I can enter the data manually using the post forms @ api/create but when I try to post it via the api, I get this error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 400</p>
        <p>Message: Bad Request.</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 400 - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is the data I tried to post:

1)

```
[
{"id":null,"label":"Workorder 1","start":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","duration":9,"ctype":"bar","werk":"a","product":"a","train_number":535435.0,"latest_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","latest_start_timebucket":9,"is_start_date_fixed":false,"assigned_start_timebucket":535435.0,"assigned_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","costs_early_start":334,"costs_late_start":334,"resource_overall_demands":334,"resource_timeslots_demands":334},
{"id":null,"label":"Workorder 1","start":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","duration":9,"ctype":"bar","werk":"a","product":"a","train_number":535435.0,"latest_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","latest_start_timebucket":9,"is_start_date_fixed":false,"assigned_start_timebucket":535435.0,"assigned_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","costs_early_start":334,"costs_late_start":334,"resource_overall_demands":334,"resource_timeslots_demands":334}
]
```

2)

```
[
{"id":null,"label":"Workorder 1","start":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","duration":9,"ctype":"bar","werk":"a","product":"a","train_number":535435,"latest_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","latest_start_timebucket":9,"is_start_date_fixed":false,"assigned_start_timebucket":535435,"assigned_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","costs_early_start":334,"costs_late_start":334,"resource_overall_demands":334,"resource_timeslots_demands":334}
]
```

3)

```
{"id":null,"label":"Workorder 1","start":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","duration":9,"ctype":"bar","werk":"a","product":"a","train_number":535435,"latest_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","latest_start_timebucket":9,"is_start_date_fixed":false,"assigned_start_timebucket":535435,"assigned_start_date":"2019-01-10T00:00:00.000Z","costs_early_start":334,"costs_late_start":334,"resource_overall_demands":334,"resource_timeslots_demands":334}
```

4)

```
{"id":1}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Did you make a POST request?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem YES

Comment: It looks like you aim to create multiple objects simultanously.

Comment: I deleted all the rows, except one, but still same error

Comment: what if you pass a dictionary (the first one for example), and *not* a list of dictionaries?

Comment: nothing, same error

Comment: If you have `django_extensions` installed you can run `python manage.py show_urls`. That will confirm the URL you're posting to is correct. Otherwise, post your urls.py file. The error message sounds like you're making the request to the wrong URL or using the wrong request method. Also post your model.

Comment: Your `data` dictionary does not match the example post data you say you're posting.

Comment: @schillingt the url is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/" and it works using the html forms to post data

Comment: @schillingt Your data dictionary does not match the example post data you say you're posting. < I dont understand what you mean. I havent posted anything via the api, yet.

Comment: The data you say you're posting includes way more items in the dictionary than the `data` dictionary you post via `r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data) `. Anyway, try adding or removing the trailing slash from your url.

Comment: @schillingt I removed the trailing slash and now I get: RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/create/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Comment: @schillingt Are you sure that this is not because Im trying to save a datetime object with a datefield?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Have you tried this, **`requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, json = data) `**

Comment: @JPG yes, Ive tried json =data and data = json.dumps(data).

Comment: Please add your urls.py too

Comment: @JPG added to the post

Answer (score 1):

When you do `requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)` it sends yoru data as form data.

It looks like you are trying to send data in a format which your API doesn't accept.

I think your API is configured to accept only JSON but you are trying to send it as form data.

Check settings from the docs at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#setting-the-parsers

Also you can try to post your data as JSON strings using `requests.post(..., json=payload)`. Reference https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the `api_...` are referring to.

But given the error message, it seems that your client is not sending a proper request.

One usefull way of debugging this is to try to make it work first with generated code from the devtools:

- Go to the browsable API from DRF
- Open devtools, go to `Network`, select `All`
- Make your POST via the browsable API
- Find the corresponding request in the devtools, right click on it and select `copy as fetch` or `copy as curl`
- Then try to run it on a browser (for fetch) or in bash (for curl) and see if it works.